# As a student, are there specific work limitations for remote working in Singapore?

Tags: students, working, singapore

Starting from September, I will attend full-time classes at ESSEC Business School in Singapore. I saw that I have to get a Student pass (I don't have many details about it right now) and that it would allow me to work no more than 16 hours per week.

Is this limit only applicable to jobs in Singapore or is it the same for remote working? For instance, can I work more than 16 hours a week if I'm working in Singapore for a company based in France?

Answer (score 2):

The [Singapore Goverment Ministry of Manpower](http://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits/work-pass-exemption-for-foreign-students) is specific about the conditions under which foreign students may work and, during the school term, those 16 hours must be part of your school's program requirements.

> If you are holding a Student Pass in Singapore, you are only allowed to work if you meet specific requirements.
>
> **Not allowed to work**
>
> You are not allowed to work if:
>
> - You are not studying in any of the approved institutions listed [*see full list on linked site*].
> - You are an exchange student doing study modules in Singapore.
>
> **Working during vacation**
>
> You can work during your vacation without a work pass if you are:
>
> - A full-time matriculated or registered student in one of the approved institutions.
> - Holding a Student Pass issued by the Immigration and Checkpoints Authority (ICA).
> - Aged 14 years and above.
>
> **Working during school term**
>
> You can work during the school term without a work pass if you meet all of the following criteria:
>
> - You are a full-time matriculated or registered student in one of the approved institutions.
> - You hold a Student Pass issued by the Immigration and Checkpoints Authority (ICA).
>
> Additionally, your work needs to meet one of these requirements:
>
> - It is for a maximum of 16 hours a week.
> - It is under an industrial attachment programme conducted by your university or educational institution. The industrial attachment can be either compulsory or elective but it must contribute towards your graduation requirements.

Comment: Oh well, I didn't understand it that way actually. I thought that when they said "Additionally, your work needs to meet one of these requirements", I could either work 16 hours per week on a job unrelated to my studies, or more if it was part of them. So I was asking what kind of job would be counted in those 16 hours, because I thought work for foreign companies wouldn't necessarily have to fit in :).

Comment: @SoniaSeddiki best to verify with your school and the Ministry, as deriving income/working remotely is frowned on in some countries, and can have negative impact on a visa.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't have much success with my school nor the Ministry. I asked the Ministry of Manpower, which redirected me to the Immigration and Checkpoint Authority, which redirected me to the Ministry of Manpower, and so on. And for my school, they didn't know anything about it. I think I'll just pass on this one, I don't want to take any risk.

Comment: @SoniaSeddiki I agree, it would be wise to not do anything, at least initially. Once you settle in to your program, you may discover that your program advisors could authorize it as part of your elective requirements.